# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rank' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I just started learning javascipt and am stumped at this error in the middle of a tutorial:

I'm trying to create a mini-game of sorts where I flip cards and find matches.

I have objects in an array and am trying to call the particular value of 'rank' depending on which card(object) is chosen.

Running the code in console gives me an error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rank' of undefined.

Javascript:

```
console.log("Up and running");

var cards = [
{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
},
{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
},
{
    rank: "king",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"
},
{
    rank: "king",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
}
];
var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert("You found a match!");
    } else alert("Sorry, try again");
}
var flipCard = function(cardId) {
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank); 
    /*issue is with calling the rank*/
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        checkForMatch();
    };
}

var createBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i ++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute("img", "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute("data-id", i);
        cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard());
        document.getElementById("game-board").appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}
createBoard();

flipCard(0);
flipCard(2);
```

Is my error due to the way I call the value from the object using cards[cardId].rank?

Comment: flipcard function needs an cardId parameter, when you call `flipcard` on click event you don't pass any parameter, and it becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a function reference to `addEventListener` (a function that call `flipCard` with a correct parameter). Then you'll have this [**problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) which you can be solved like this:

```
var createBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i ++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute("img", "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute("data-id", i);

        // ############################################# 

        (function(index) {
            cardElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
                flipCard(index);
            });
        })(i);

        // ############################################# 

        document.getElementById("game-board").appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}
```

or using `forEach` instead of `for` which make things a lot simpler:

```
var createBoard = function() {
    cards.forEach(function(card, i) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute("img", "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute("data-id", i);

        // no need to wrap this in an immediately invoked function expression (as this whole code is wrapped in the callback of forEach)
        cardElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
            flipCard(i);
        });

        document.getElementById("game-board").appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard());`

to

`cardElement.addEventListener("click", function(){ flipCard(i); });`

**UPDATE start**

to

`cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard.bind(null, i));`

to avoid closuring case mentioned in comments

**UPDATE end**

Explanation: when calling `addEventListener`, second argument must be a function, but you pass result of the call of the function `flipCard`, which returns undefined.

Another mistake in your code, is that you call it without arguments, while it expects `cardId` as argument, and when it does not get it, it takes undefined element from the `cards` array

Comment: Don't forget this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example!

Answer (score 0):

Just update

`cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard());`

**To**

`cardElement.addEventListener("click", function(e){ flipCard(e.target.dataset.id); });`